# How to use pexpect to manage processes, but just redirect all output to /dev/null

Tags: pexpect

I have a python script that starts a bunch of processes, but doesn't use the expect features to interact with processes.  So I encounter issues where it seems the stdout buffer gets full and causes processes stdout to block.  Is there a way to just have stdout/stderr redirected to /dev/null or just flushed?  I have tried using logfile feature and opening /dev/null, but this still requires reading from process.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: A [mcve] please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can direct all output to `/dev/null` so there will be no data waiting to be read. For example:

```
pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash', ['-c', '/your/command ... > /dev/null 2>&1'])
```

Comment: Using this method, is there a way to get PID of spawned process instead of the bash shell?

Comment: you can `bash -c "exec /the/command >& /dev/null"` so the pid would be the same as bash.